# I want to pass variable value into url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

The following code is not working.please check and give possible solution

{

```
  ("button").click(function(){
   var scity =$("input:text").val();
   alert (scity);

});
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?mode=xml&q="+scity+",
dataType: "xml",
success:parseXML});
});
```

}

```
i try to enter the value of city in url. but its not working.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you notice any error logged in the console?

You have a typo, but I'm not sure if the code you posted is exactly the one you are using. If it is, try removing the `+"` that comes after `scity`, in the url property of your AJAX call. Also, try moving the `var scity` out of the click function. Like so:

```
var scity;

    $("button").click(function() {
        scity = $("input:text").val();
        alert(scity);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?mode=xml&q=" + scity,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXML
    });
```